# Gradle plugin, running tasks twice during build

Tags: android, plugins, groovy, gradle

I'm trying to extend functionality of gradle [Android plugin](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Tasks).
The point is, that I need to run same tasks twice on one build (in fact the whole chain of tasks till connectedInstrumentTest), and as I couldn't manage how to do it using only gradle, I decided to write my own plugin that will be an extention to existing Android plugin.
So, now I'm trying to use functionality of Android plugin in my, using such groovy code:

```
void apply(Project project) {

    project.plugins.apply(JavaPlugin.class)
    project.plugins.apply(AndroidPlugin.class)

    this.project = project
    this.logger = project.logger

    AndroidPlugin a = new AndroidPlugin()
    a.apply(project)
```

But, trying to compile it, I get an error:

**import com.jvoegele.gradle.plugins.android.AndroidPlugin**

I'm using such build.gradle to compile my plugin:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
mavenCentral()
}
  dependencies {
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.4.2'
}
}
apply plugin: 'groovy'
dependencies {
compile gradleApi()
compile localGroovy()
}
```

Also, as I'm first time using groovy, I have some difficulties with overriding methods. I tried this, but it doesn't seem to work:

```
 MetaMethod proces = AndroidPackageTask.metaClass.pickMethod("process")
    proces = {
       println("ggggggg")
    }
```

So, can anyone tell what is wrong compiling plugin, or how to use tasks twice during one build?

Comment: What error do you get?  That's an import statement

Comment: I have an error for missing Android plugin, like this:
import com.jvoegele.gradle.plugins.android.AndroidPlugin
I think, there is something wrong with my build.gradle, but I don't know what

Answer (score 1):

It isn't possible to run a task twice in the same build. What you can do is to create two tasks with the same type and configuration (note that multiple tasks can be configured in one go), or (as a last resort) launch two embedded builds (task type `GradleBuild`) that share a build script.

Comment: What do you mean "tasks with the same type and configuration"? Can you give some simple example, please?

Comment: Declare five `Copy` task with same `destinationDir`: `5.times { task "task$it"(type: Copy) { destinationDir = file("some/dir") } }`

Comment: Yes, thank you, that works fine with this tasks, but I can't do it for tasks using plugin, like:
`android {
....
}`
so, how can I use them again?

Comment: There is no generic way to do this. You may have to write specialized code to copy the necessary tasks. Or question your whole approach.

Comment: On top of Peter's excellent answer your code and error is just weird. You are referencing the official gradle plugin, but trying to use a task from the 3rd party android plugin (com.jvoegele.gradle.plugins.android.AndroidPlugin). I'm not sure what you are trying to do but those 2 plugins are probably not compatible with each other.